# Full text search asterisk returns wrong result

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index, full-text-catalog

I have a Ship table with FTS index, which was created as:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Ship 
(       
    Name 
)
KEY INDEX PK_Ship_Id
ON MyCatalog
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO, STOPLIST OFF;
```

And when I run query bellow:

```
select Name From Ship where CONTAINS(Name, N'"n*"');
```

I get wrong result, for instance "Vitamin D3 1000 Iu". 
But I want get only rows where name field has any word starts with 'n' char.

Comment: Then you should not use contains, use like 'n*' if you want i to start with N.

Comment: Name field can has more than one word, and I want search 'n' char in every. For example CONTAINS(Name, N'"lol*" and "lala*"') exactly finds "name name lollll asd lalaaaa" string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTS engine has strange 'feature', when you try find somethings as `CONTAINS(Name, N'"n*"')`, it searches all numbers because it keeps numbers as NN.

The best decision which was founded is in these two cases(`CONTAINS(Name, N'"n*"'), CONTAINS(Name, N'"nn*"')`) use "like" search.